# mjpeg and h264 codecs

Tags: video, video-encoding, h.264, mjpeg

What is the difference between mjpeg and h264?

Comment: The currently accepted answer is wrong, can you please change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first know that The H.264 & MPEG-4 AVC & MPEG-4 part 10 are the same. check [this](http://video-codecs.blogspot.com/)

now

1. With moving cameras or images of high activity areas, MPEG4 and H.264 provide little bandwidth savings relative to MJPEG.
2. Proper network design requires factoring in worse case scenarios so you will need to dedicate the same amount of bandwidth whether or not you use MJPEG, MPEG4 or H.264.
3. MJPEG provides higher quality because of no intra-frame compression.
4. Unlike MJPEG, with MPEG-4 vendors deviate from standards, increasing potential integration costs.

**While H.264 generally reduces bandwidth consumption significantly**, it depends on multiple factors (including complexity, streaming mode, frame rate and i frame rate). VBR vs CBR selection is especially important, having a especially large impact on use and performance. Finally, while H.264 can deliver the same visible image quality as MJPEG, depending on the settings you use (especially streaming mode), you can easily generate worse quality.

Comment: MJPEG does have intra-frame compression; that's what JPEG is. It doesn't have any inter-frame compression.

Comment: Let me elaborate. Just about everything about your comment is wrong.

1. H.264's bandwidth advantage over MJPEG isn't little, even in high-activity areas or with moving cameras, unless you're shooting at very low framerates (<20fps) so there's tons of change between frames.

2. "Proper network design..." -- you sound like you're stuck thinking of the world of networked security cameras; most people shooting video - even including programmers- don't need to be concerned about network design.

Comment: 3. MJPEG does have intra-frame compression; that's what JPEG is. It doesn't have any inter-frame compression. There's nothing which would force you to encode H.264 at lower quality than MJPEG- even AVC-Intra will produce higher quality video at a given bitrate than MJPEG will.

4. [There is no standard for MJPEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MJPEG#Criticisms); there is a very strictly defined standard for H.264. There are all kinds of interop issues with different vendors' MJPEGs and I don't see any such interop issues with H.264.

Comment: The benefit of not-having inter-frame compression is not b/w saving but suitability for editing. The more inter-frame compression the more work a non-linear editing tool has to do. H.264 can be used in intra-only mode too, e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVC-Intra and http://www.amwa.tv/projects/AS-11.shtml.

Answer (score 3):

Mjpeg is just a list of jpeg files in a single file or data stream. There is no interframe compression. Put another way, every frame is a key frame.

h264 is very different from Mjpeg - start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC

(Mpeg (no 'j') is different from Mjpeg, but very similar to H264)

Answer (score 0):

Video compression is achieved from 2 forms of prediction:

- **Intra** prediction: using information from within the **same** frame.
- **Inter** prediction: using information from a **reference** frame.

Inter prediction is generally a lot better, as it allows areas of the video that are similar between frames to be encoded very cheaply. This is where H.264 gains most of its compression.

A single JPEG image is just an intra frame, and MJPEG is just a sequence of JPEG images. MJPEG has no inter frames at all.

In fact even an H.264 intra frame will offer much better compression than a JPEG frame (this is partly why Google pushed WebP).

For most use cases H.264 will have **much** better compression than MJPEG, but the encode/decode process is a lot more complex, which is why things without much computing power e.g. webcams spit out MJPEG.

It would have to be a rather pathological case for an good H.264 encoder to perform as badly as a good MJPEG encoder, e.g. randomly generated pixel values.